# How do I create a message that flashes after an AJAX form returns an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, message, flash-message

I'm using Rails 5.  I want to create a message that flashes on my page after I submit an AJAX form and an error comes back.  I'm not using twitter bootstrap and would only consider using that if it doesn't screw up any of the other styling I already have.  Anyway, on my view I have this

```
<div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-success"></div>
```

and in my controller I have this

```
displayError('#{error_msg}')
```

which invokes this coffee script ...

```
@displayError = (msg) ->
  ...

  $("#error_explanation").text(msg)
```

As you guess, right now, the message just displays in plain text . I would like it to flash and then disappear.  How do I do that?

Comment: I've used the gem `unobtrisive_flash` before and it's really easy to implement.
https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/unobtrusive_flash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the message to fade out after a set amount of time, then change that last line of CoffeeScript to:

```
$("#error_explanation").text(msg).delay(3000).fadeOut()
```

If you need something a bit more complex (e.g. don't fade out if hovered, stacked notifications, dismiss button etc), or ready-styled - then you might want to investigate using a JS library such as [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).

Comment: This looks very promising.  Is this a Gem?  Or am I just copying the JS/CSS files?

Comment: @Dave: either copy into your project, or use the CDN links provided in the repository readme. There is a `toastr-rails` gem, but it looks like that hasn't been updated in a while.

Answer (score 1):

this should help get you started:

```
show_ajax_message = (msg, type) ->
  $("#flash-message").html "<div id='flash-#{type}'>#{msg}</div>"
  $("#flash-#{type}").delay(5000).slideUp 'slow'

$(document).ajaxComplete (event, request) ->
  msg = request.getResponseHeader("X-Message")
  type = request.getResponseHeader("X-Message-Type")
  show_ajax_message msg, type
```

https://www.google.com/search?q=flash+messages+session+rails+ajax

Answer (score -1):

Based on nothing but your coffee script, here's how:

`Not familiar with CoffeeScript and its syntax, so here's plain JS code.`

`setTimeout(function() {
  $('#visitLink').hide()
}, 2000);`

That'll make the message disappear after 2 seconds.

Comment: The error message is actually in  the DIV with id = "error_explanation" that I included in my question.  Even substituting "#error_explanation" for visit link, your code just makes it instantly disappear, but the typical Flash notices fade out and also have more styling to make the message more prominent to the user. How do I simulate all fo that?

Comment: If you want to add animations and all that, you have 2 choices. You toggle a class with jQuery 'visible' and 'hidden' and apply your animation using transform with CSS. Or, use jQuery http://api.jquery.com/animate/  . Although I would recommend CSS since it's easier to the User and more performant.

Comment: As for why it disappears instantly, I'd need more code to see why's that.

Comment: It disappears instantly because "$('#...').hide()" takes effect immediately.